# Iterate over database Record

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have database record which is like this

```
[#<Event:0x00007fbe7372de48
  @timezone="Europe/London">,
  @data={:foo=>"bar", :larry=>"lobster"},
  @id="first_event",
  @name="page_viewed",
  @occurred_at=Thu, 18 Feb 2021 21:16:57 UTC +00:00>,

#<Event:0x00007fbe7372de48
  @timezone="Europe/London">,
  @data={:foo=>"bar", :larry=>"test2"},
  @id="second_event",
  @name="page_viewed",
  @occurred_at=Thu, 18 Feb 2021 21:17:57 UTC +00:00>,

 #<Event:0x00007fbe7372f2e8
  @timezone="Europe/London">,
  @data={:foo=>"bar", :larry=>"lobster"},
  @id="second_event",
  @name="rfq_created",
  @occurred_at=Thu, 18 Feb 2021 21:19:57 UTC +00:00>

#<Event:0x00007fbe7372f2e8
  @timezone="Europe/London">,
  @data={:foo=>"bar", :larry=>"lobster"},
  @id="second_event",
  @name="rfq_created",
  @occurred_at=Thu, 18 Feb 2021 22:18:57 UTC +00:00>...]
```

Now i want fetch list of records when event name(@name) is `page_viewed`, `started` and `selected`  i want to fetch only first event occurred record and if event name(@name) is `rfq_created` and `purchased` i want all the records of  event name `rfq_created` and `purchased`

Here is what i have done :

```
 EVENTS = { "unique_kpi" => { "page_viewed" => 'UVisit',          
                              "start" => 'PVisit',
                              "selected" => 'SVisit' 
                             },
          "non_unique_kpi"=> {"rfq_created" => 'RfqCreated',
                              "purchased" => 'Purchased' 
                              }
}


def key_performance_indicators
  key_indicators = events.each_with_object({}) do |event, hash|
    if EVENTS["non_unique_kpi"].keys.include?(event.name)
      hash[event.name] = []  unless hash.has_key?(event.name)
      hash[event.name] << event
    else
      hash[event.name] = event unless hash.has_key?(event.name)
    end

  key_indicators.map do |key, value|
    kpi_class = indicator_class(key)
    "{kpi_class}".constantize.new(event: value)
  end
end


def indicator_class(kpi_key)
  EVENTS.find { |_k, hash| return hash[kpi_key] if hash.keys.include?(kpi_key) }
end
```

I want to refactor this in good way is there any other approach we can do this ? Please help.

Comment: You can also do `(hash[event.name] ||= [ ]) << event` if you want a more minimal version, or `hash[event.name] ||= event` as well. Note that `"#{x}"` and `x` are practically the same if `x` is already a string. Do you mean `indicator_class(key).constantize.new(...)`? It would be nice if your `indicator_class` method did the `constantize` for you from a readability perspective.

Comment: Tip: `hash.keys.include?(kpi_key)` is *extraordinarily expensive* to do on a non-trivial sized Hash. It pulls all the keys, stuffs them into a throw-away temporary array, then does a linear scan of that array for your entry. What you probably mean is `hash.key?(...)` which is a very quick test. What you really mean is likely `EVENTS.find { |_k, h| h[kpi_key] }` and you're done.